# How to add a new .php page/view in a subdirectory of a my website which contains a .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using this [php login script](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal) as a jumpstart for my website

This is my directory listing for the `views` folder of my site:

```
>_installation
>classes
>config
>libraries
>views
    .htaccess
    logged_in.php       //works fine
    newpage.php         //new page returns a Error 403
    not_logged_in.php   //works fine
    register.php        //works fine
 index.php
 register.php
```

The file `.htaccess` file in `views` folder contains:

```
# This file prevents that your .php view files are accessed directly from the outside
<Files ~ "\.(htaccess|php)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

I'm wondering why the newly added `nawpage.php` in the same folder `views` returns an **Access forbidden! Error 403** everytime I access it. But, the remaining .php files in `views` works perfectly.

This is the complete error details:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11

Can someone help me fix and understand this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` literally forbids everyone from accessing your `.php` files.  You shouldn't be able to access other pages. Is there any other configuration you're not sharing? What are your files permissions (shouldn't be a problem as you're running on Windows)?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to use this login script https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal. I'm using xampp running in Windows 10 @D4V1D

Comment: As per the documentation: "*This script comes with a handy .htaccess in the views folder that denies direct access to the files within the folder (**so that people cannot render the views directly**).*". So it's perfectly normal you cannot access to `newpage.php` (btw, is `nawpage.php` in your post a typo?) directly. What you should wonder is why you *can* access other pages when your `.htaccess` explicitely defines it as not possible. Are you accessing them directly (eg. `http://localhost/myproject/views/register.php`)?

Comment: I tried accessing it as `http://localhost/myproject/views/newpage.php` but I know it is wrong. I also tried to access it using a `<a href="newpage.php"></a>` html tag from a different page which is also inside the `views` folder but still, it returns Error 403. Do you have an idea on how can I access it?

Comment: Well, your `.htaccess` prevents anyone from accessing it so yes, I know how to access it: remove the `deny from all` in your `.htaccess`. What do you mean by "*I know it is wrong*"?

Comment: Its wrong because it will still return error 403. Removing `deny from all` did not work sir please help

Comment: What do you mean by *did not work*? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Let me answer your question.

You can read your php file for example you can write your index.php file

include "view/newpage.php";

It will work fine. But you can't access view folder any file directly from your browser. You can access these file from your php code or only from that server end.